# What keyboard layout is compatible with CK62 PRO?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have this bluetooth keyboard, CK62 PRO (from MOTOSPEED):

[image]

On windows 10, I am able to write `ã` using <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> and letter <kbd>a</kbd>.

[image]

I tried some layouts on Ubuntu 23.10 like English (UK, intl. with dead keys) but the result is a `¬` char and if I try <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> single quote to get a double quote I got `@` instead.

Any tips?

Comment: Maybe run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and choose 104 as keyboard model instead of 105.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson tried but it did not work